# Can I use a power bank which shows output as 6V 9V 12V to run an RC car which uses 6 AA batteries?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, output, remote-control

I'm currently stuck at home and found an old RC car which uses 6 AA batteries. Buying new non rechargable batteries everytime i play with it is gonna be heavy on the pockets. I thought maybe if I can power it by using a usb cable and connect the wires which has the power input to the car and Use a powerbank which I have to run it. Would that work?

Comment: How are battery connected? In series or in parallel or few serial and then in parallel? You need to find out...

Comment: What about buying rechargeable AA batteries?

Comment: The batteries are connected in series. I know buying rachargable AA s is better. But I thought I already have a powerbank which I thought is the same as a rechargable battery pack. Tbe output also shows similat V. Hence made a plan to give it a try

Answer (score 1):

It should work, because they are normally in series connection.

If the batteries are in series, then you could use the device with 1.5V Alkaline cells and you would have 6*1.5=9V with possibly 800mAh or till 1200mAh. The 9V mode (USB 3.0 PD cable for 9V) of your powerbank should be okay.

With this [USB 3.0 PD device](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005005334502551.html) it is possible to select the output-voltage.

You can try it first with 5V.